# Swift firestore updateData doesnt create new Document

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

i have an array where i want to add some data to it. if the document doesnt exist it should create a new one but this doesnt work. It works only with already created documents. Here is my Code:

```
    let washingtonRef = db.collection("ShoppingLists").document(valueset["listId"]!)

    uploadData["productId"] = productID
    uploadData["sellerId"] = sellerId
    washingtonRef.setData([
        "products": FieldValue.arrayUnion([uploadData])
        ])
```

Comment: why is the title saying "updateData" but not in the context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have forgotten the `merge` flag in `setData`:

```
washingtonRef.setData([
           "products": FieldValue.arrayUnion([uploadData])
        ], merge: true)
```

If you use the `setData` method to store a document, existing documents will be overwritten! If you want to update an existing document with `setData`, you need to add the `merge: true` flag